# Why is there a large gap formed beneath my div element when I display it using a JS toggle()?

Tags: javascript, css, html, display

I got my page working how I wanted it (based on the previous question I asked). However, when I display the timeline (default is display:none) it creates a large gap of empty space beneath it. How can I remove this empty space? I just want the timeline to replace the image when it is clicked and vice-versa.

Here is my [code pen](http://codepen.io/thevampiire/pen/YZeBjj/)

```
I don't know what code to include here.
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Can you clarify a bit?

Comment: Go to my code pen. When the page first renders everything is ok. Now when you click the image I am able hide the image and display the list instead. However, when the list displays it creates a large gap of blank space extended beneath it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using position:relative and giving css top value. That is causing this issue. I have done some change in css with position and top values. That works as you require.

```
#timeline{
  position:absolute;
  background-color:beige;
  /*top:-829px;*/
  top:210px;
  width: 755px;
  height: 827px;
  margin-left: 180px;
}
```

Hope this resolves your issue.

Comment: Yes that fixed it. I don't know why I had to do top: -829 to get it to the top of the image before. So now you are saying position absolute which fixes it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

change the css,

```
#main-image-div{
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 750px;
  height: 400px;
}
#main-image-div img{
  max-width: 100%;
}
#timeline{
  position: absolute;
  left: 0; 
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Hope this will solve the issue.

Comment: you should create a structure first.

Answer (score 0):

I created a nicer toggle effect and i think that's what you wanted.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dvdLpY

```
var img = $('img');
var list = $('.list');
list.hide();

img.click(function(){
  $(this).fadeToggle(function(){
    list.fadeToggle();
  });
});

list.click(function(){
  $(this).fadeToggle(function(){
    img.fadeToggle();
  });
});
```